# Django Rest Framework - serializer code not executing

Tags: serialization, hash, passwords, django-rest-framework, password-hash

I am trying to implement a user registration with password hashing.

**The problem** is that the password is saved raw (as it was typed).

For some reason, I think the **create method in the serializer is not called**.

**Doesn't matter if I comment the method out or not comment it out**, and try to register, same result - is saves the user to the database without hashing the password. It means that the code doesn't execute?

**Views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsCreationOrIsAuthenticated,)
```

**Serizliers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User(
                first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                username=validated_data['username'],
                last_name=validated_data['last_name']
            )
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user
```

I have been struggling with this for a while - can't has the password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `create` method is tabbed to a point where it is within the `Meta` class instead of the serializer class. You need to untab it once so it is on the right line.

Comment: Please check your indentation for `create()` method

Comment: wow what a stupid mistake.. thanks a lot! now its working.

Answer (score 2):

The create function is within the target class, it must be inside the main class, remove an indentation tab

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            username=validated_data['username'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your `create` method in `serializers.py`, do this work by overriding the `perform_create()` method in your `views.py`. To do some extra work on creation of an object, DRF provides this hook. This will make the code more clean and DRY.

As per the DRF docs,

> Save and deletion hooks:
>
> The following methods are provided by the mixin classes, and provide
>   easy overriding of the object save or deletion behavior.
>
> perform_create(self, serializer) - Called by CreateModelMixin when
>   saving a new object instance.
>    perform_update(self, serializer) -
>   Called by UpdateModelMixin when saving an existing object instance.
>   perform_destroy(self, instance) - Called by DestroyModelMixin when
>   deleting an object instance.
>   These hooks are particularly useful for
>   setting attributes that are implicit in the request, but are not part
>   of the request data.

You can do that by:

**views.py**

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    user = User(
            first_name=serializer.data['first_name'],
            username=serializer.data['username'],
            last_name=serializer.data['last_name']
        )
    user.set_password(serializer.data['password'])
    user.save()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but apparently there was a problem with the  indentation of the create method.. really stupid